# What does the while (reader.Peek() != -1) condition mean?

Tags: c#, server, backend

With the help of a tutorial im writing a WebServer in C# to further profound my knowledge in C#

Heres the Code and my question:

```
    private void HandleClient(TcpClient client)
    {

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

        String msg = "";

        while (reader.Peek() != -1)
        {

            msg += reader.ReadLine() + "\n";
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Request: \n" + msg);
    }
```

What does the "!=1" in "while (reader.Peek() != -1)" mean?

Comment: `reader.Peek()` returns the codepoint value of the next character in the stream, or -1 if there are no more, aka the end of the stream. So basically this one just says "While there is more to read". You could also check the result of `reader.ReadLine()` which will return `null` in this instance. A more typical loop would be: `string line; while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) { ... }`

Comment: `Peek` returns -1 if there are no more characters to be read

Comment: If you really want to augment your C# knowledge you really should start searching the docs. It is all there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.peek?view=netframework-4.8 I say this not to mock you but because learning how to search for unknown info is one of the fundamental steps in learning something in this field

Comment: The whole while statement can be simplified to `var msg = reader.ReadToEnd();` which is also much more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

`reader.Peek()` tells you which the next character in the stream is without reading it (i.e. it is left in the stream)

When there are no more characters it returns -1. This way you know that nothing more is coming.

Furthermore, since you are reading a character stream, -1 is not a valid character, therefore you can clearly identify the end of stream condition as it is not in the valid range for characters (0 to 65535, bounds included).

`!=` is the *not equal to* operator in c#, therefore the line `reader.Peek() != -1` means

> get the next character without removing it from the stream and check it against -1 (which means EndOfStream). If they are different then the result of the comparison is `true` otherwise `false`.

For further information on the `peek` method, see [Peek at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.peek?view=netframework-4.8), while for the operators, see [Operators at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/).